# Video DownloadHelper extension ignores "no history" settings

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, add-on

I'm posting this here because the [support site](http://bugzilla.downloadhelper.net:8080/) for this [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) won't work for me from within TorBrowser - and as a warning for anyone else who might be as stupid as me to try using extensions within TorBrowser.

This extension ignores TorBrowser's "Never remember history" default setting.  I recently used it to download a few YouTube videos, and several days later, when I next used TorBrowser, I found that all the videos I had downloaded in the previous session were listed in TorBrowser's history. Is there any remedy to fix this problem?

Comment: Dear user1128, This should be stated as an question and answer. I try to edit this into that format.

Comment: Yes, StackExchange **prefers** posts in question-and-answer format, but does not **require** them.  Plus, AFAIK, the Tor developers don't provide any better place to post feedback or non-question comments about their software.

Answer (score 1):

Generally extentions and addons may have an undesirable consequences if added to Tor Browser. Sometimes the undesirable consequences are observable (at least it can be seen and thus, the user can decide to undo the extensions and/or addons if she desires to do so) and sometimes the undesirable consequences are not readily observable (in this case the user may use the extensions and/or addons for a long time without realization of what is happening). This last case is particularly harmful. In the end, There are so many extensions and addons and so many things may go wrong that no amount of reasonable time and energy may sort them out. Thus, it is advisable not to use any extension or addon with Tor Browser beyond what is already added by Tor Browser crew. By the way, I have tried the support site: http://bugzilla.downloadhelper.net:8080/ and it does not work for me either.